# ControllerAdvice ResponseBodyAdvice failed to enclose a String response

Tags: rest, spring-boot

Not sure why, but when an endpoint return a String, the ResponseBodyAdvice always throws a Casting exception.  Any other data type such as Long, List worked as desired, only the String data got exception. Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

```
@RestController
public class AppController {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AppController.class);

    @RequestMapping(path = "/hello",
                    method = GET)
    public String hello() {
        logger.info("... AppController.hello()");

        return "hello, world!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/timestamp",
                    method = GET)
    public long timestamp() {
        logger.info("... AppController.timestamp()");
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

here is the adviser:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResponseAdviser implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ResponseAdviser.class);

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType,
                            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        logger.trace("... ResponseAdviser.supports()");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body,
                                  MethodParameter returnType,
                                  MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                  ServerHttpRequest request,
                                  ServerHttpResponse response) {
        logger.info("... ResponseAdviser.beforeBodyWrite()");

        Response resp = new Response();
        resp.setData(body);

        return resp;
    }
}
```

And the Reponse class is basically, adding a timestamp and enclose endpoint returned data

```
@Data
public class Response {
    private Date   timestamp;
    private Object data;

    public Response() {
        this.timestamp = new Date();
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.phan.message.Response cannot be cast to java.lang.String] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.phan.message.Response cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.getContentLength(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:41) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.addDefaultHeaders(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:260) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:113) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ? . May be there is a easier way which we can suggest.

Comment: Basically, I like to return my Response container that includes a few pieces of information along with the return from the endpoint.  i.e timestamp, and endpoint returned data. In this case, "hello, world!"

Comment: can you put full stack trace

Comment: just added the stack trace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this code below:

```
 @Configuration
 public class WebConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
        converters.add(0, new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me too

Answer (score 5):

**Reason:**

The root cause of `ClassCastException` thrown is that you convert the response type from `String` to `Response` in the method `ResponseAdviser.beforeBodyWrite`.

When your return type of a controller request method is `String`, the `HttpMessageConverter` instance used to convert the return value is `StringHttpMessageConverter`.

The sequence of converters to use when processing your return value of a controller method is like this:
[image]

`ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` cannot process `String` return type.

As we know, before write and flush the response, `ContentLength` should be calculated(when add http headers). The implements of `StringHttpMessageConverter.getContentLength` is like this:
[image]

We can see, the type of input parameter str is `String`, but actually, the response type has already been modified to `Response`. So the `ClassCastException`  thrown.

**Solution:**

Tell spring framework, don't use `StringHttpMessageConverter` to process `String` return type in controller method. You just need to add a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in front of `StringHttpMessageConverter`.
sample code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> 
        converters) {

        WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
        converters.add(0, new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }

}
```

Why `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` won't throw the `ClassCastException`? Just take a look at the implements(in its super class `AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter`):
[image]

The type of input parameter object is `Object`, so it can process both `String` and `Response`.

Comment: Very Nicely explained . This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

In the `ResponseBodyAdvice` class, add the `beforeBodyWrite` method:

```
@Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType,
                                  MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                  ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
      ...

        Response resp = new Response();
        resp.setData(body);

        //返回值body为String类型时
        if (body != null && body instanceof String) {
            try {
                response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resp);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `@RestController` annotation to identify your rest endpoint, if you would like to attach an `Advice` to it you have to use the `@RestControllerAdvice` annotation designed for rest endpoints.

Comment: @RestControllerAdvice still gave me the "Response can not cast to String" exception

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the return type of `beforeBodyWrite` method and your `requestmapping` method should be same. You may try always return the Response in your controller...

All other types like fastJson or javabean have no errors except String. So I write additional code to handle String types. You can overwrite the `Response`'s `toString()`, and if the coming type is `String` then you return `Response.toString()`. This may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following code, override the `extendMessageConverters` method and remove the converters which instance of `StringHttpMessageConverter` class, as you don't need them at all.

By the way, If you choose to override `configureMessageConverters` method as your solution, it will work, but in the meantime, the properties you put in `application.yml` will not have any effects cause the default configuration method(which can load the properties by file) will not execute.

```
@Configuration
public class RestfulResponseConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.removeIf(httpMessageConverter -> httpMessageConverter instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter);
  }
}
```